# I'm getting an (for me) unexplained index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, tree, fractals

I am trying to make a fractal, but for some reason I get an Index out of bounds exeption at line 50 and 41, but to me it seems perfectly fine. I have tried several things but it only runs if do takken.get(0).draw(g2d), anything higher than 0 will give me an error. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated

```
    package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
public class FractalTree extends JPanel {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Week 1");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
    frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setContentPane(new FractalTree());
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
ArrayList<Tak> takken = new ArrayList<Tak>();

public FractalTree(){

}

public void clearTakken(){
    for(int k = 0; k <=takken.size(); k++){
        takken.remove(0);
    }
}

public void addTak(Tak tak){
    takken.add(tak);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    draw(g2d);
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
    Tak beginTak = new Tak(100,90, 600, 400, 600, 500);
    takken.add(beginTak);
    for(int j = 0; j <=3; j++) {
       for(int i = 0; i <= takken.size(); i++) {
            takken.get(0).draw(g2d);
            takken.get(1).draw(g2d);
        }
    }
}

}
```

""

```
package com.company;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

public class Tak extends FractalTree{
double lengte;
double hoek;
int xEind;
int yEind;
double xBegin;
double yBegin;
final double factor = 0.67 / Math.sqrt(2);

public Tak(double l, double h, int xE, int yE, double xB, double yB){
    lengte = l;
    hoek = h;
    xEind = xE;
    yEind = yE;
    xBegin = xB;
    yBegin = yB;
}

public double getHoek(){
    return hoek;
}
public double getLengte(){
    return lengte;
}

public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
    g2d.drawLine((int)xBegin, (int)yBegin, xEind, yEind);
    Tak tak1 = new Tak((lengte * 0.67), hoek / 2, xEind, yEind, xEind + (lengte*factor), yEind + (lengte*factor));
    addTak(tak1);
    Tak tak2 = new Tak((lengte * 0.67), hoek / 2, xEind, yEind, xEind - (lengte*factor), yEind + (lengte*factor));
    addTak(tak2);
}
```

}

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out-of-bounds for length 1
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:372)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:440)
at com.company.FractalTree.draw(FractalTree.java:50)
at com.company.FractalTree.paintComponent(FractalTree.java:41)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1075)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:908)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1084)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(JLayeredPane.java:590)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(JComponent.java:908)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5263)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBufferedImpl(RepaintManager.java:1633)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1608)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1546)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1061)
at java.desktop/java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(GraphicsCallback.java:39)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(SunGraphicsCallback.java:78)
at java.desktop/sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(SunGraphicsCallback.java:115)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.paint(Container.java:1998)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.paint(Window.java:3926)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:868)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:840)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:840)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:815)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:764)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:69)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1880)
at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: This looks problematic: `for(int k = 0; k <=takken.size(); k++){` you surely mean `k < takken.size();` ? or why not just `takken.clear();` rather than the loop? I'm also not sure why you have a loop in your `FractalTree.draw()` method since you access the same indices each time (0 and 1)? Again, this should likely be `i < takken.size()` in any case.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! such a stupid mistake haha, it works now, but any idea why it isn't printing a fractal, but just the first tak?

Comment: I think the majority of your issues are as a result of poor design. Why does `Tak` extend `FractalTree`, does the relationship `Tak` is a `FractalTree` make sense? Then weird circular references by adding to the `takken` list whilst drawing, which if you weren't always calling `takken.get(int)` on indices `0` and `1` would result in an eventual `OutOfMemory` error.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the second element which is null in the array while you added just one element in this method

```
public void draw(Graphics2D g2d){
    Tak beginTak = new Tak(100,90, 600, 400, 600, 500);
    takken.add(beginTak);
    for(int j = 0; j <=3; j++) {
       for(int i = 0; i <= takken.size(); i++) {
            takken.get(0).draw(g2d);
            takken.get(1).draw(g2d);
        }
    }
}
```

add another Tak element to the array and it will work .